# Changing Android launch activity to another activity = app doesn't load

Tags: java, android, android-activity

**Aim:** Wanting to change the starting `Activity` of my application.

**Status:** After changing the starting `Activity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. I try to run the application on my device, but the application will not build..

Would really appreciate the help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.example.VLPage_Activity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.example.VLMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.example.VLCopyright" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.example.VLPage_Activity" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.example.VLVideoPlayer" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.example.VLExpansionFiles" />

<provider android:name="com.example.example.VLZipUriProvider" 
     android:authorities="com.example.example.VLZipUriProvider"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you post your Manifest, please?

Comment: but the application will not build.. ? means what ? Are you getting any syntax error ? Any exception ? Also add your manifest here

Comment: Sadly I am not getting anything, no errors, no nothing. (Question Updated with manifest)

Comment: Probably because you now have VMPage_Activity in your manifest twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user1676075

For all those who are having the same problem, its because I had declared the same activity twice in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Thanks again everyone!